# Can I change the order of comments displayed using comment plugin?

Tags: comments, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

I see you can change the order within the moderation tools but so far in my research can't see how to change the display order (chron. reverse chron. etc) on the actual page where the comment plugin is being used. Any info would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the comments plugin does not have any control, only  the user seeing the comments plugin has control over the way they see the comments. There's a little triangle beside the # of posts that allows the user to control the order.